# Linewise lexicographic sort of a file with a catch

Tags: c++, sorting

Although I am not happy with the title of this question and this might be an odd question; bear with me, please.

So I have text files with content as follows:

```
 & AAABBAB
 this
 & AAAAAAB 
 is
 & BCAAAA
 an
 & BBBBBA
 example
 & BABABAB
 text
```

where every other line starts with an identifier ('&'). Lines with said identifier should be lexicographically sorted, but I need it in a way such that the next line is dragged along to the new position in the output file with it.

This is what I am hoping to be the content of the output file.

```
 & AAAAAAB 
 is
 & AAABBAB
 this
 & BABABAB
 text
 & BBBBBA
 example
 & BCAAAA
 an
```

With this, I can get the file content line-by-line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream is("test.txt");
    string str;
    while(getline(is, str))
    {
        cout<<str<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish what I am looking for? Thanks for your help!

Comment: First of all you should store all those lines into a `std::vector<std::string>` for example, before you can start to sort them, no?

Comment: @user0042 not necessarily [in that form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46528972/85371), but yeah, you can't sort things you don't have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd bundle the pairs together while reading, making them easy to sort:

```
vector<pair<string, string>> vec; // first is identifier
vec.reserve(1000);

bool first = true;
while(getline(is, str))
{
    if (first)
        vec.emplace_back(str, string());
    else
        vec.back().second = str;
    first = !first;
}

sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can gather your lines by pairs into a vector of `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` :

```
using line_t = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;
std::vector<line_t> lines;
line_t pair_line;
while (std::getline(is, pair_line.first) &&
       std::getline(is, pair_line.second)) {
    lines.push_back(pair_line);
}
```

and sort them by their `.first`:

```
std::sort(begin(lines), end(lines),
          [](auto const &l1, auto const &l2)
            { return l1.first < l2.first; });
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0854931208b8158d)

Comment: `std::pair` comes with `operator<` already defined in the way required for this problem, so no need to pass a function object to `std::sort()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

View the entire file as a map of key and value pairs, read into a `std::map<std::string,std::string>`, then output the map. Since string compares are lexicographic by default and maps have ordered keys, the map will do the sorting for you.

Comment: You can do this but it is less efficient than using vector.

Comment: Yes, but the overhead of reading the file itself is likely to overshadow the impact of using a `map` over a `vector`.

Comment: A pair of short strings requires 64 bytes.  Putting them in a map requires another ~32 bytes, for 50% overhead in memory utilization.

Comment: @owacoder I like the approach! Thanks for sharing the idea. Also, thank you for pointing out the overhead, John

Answer (score 1):

Here's a take that works nicely if you have a file that's too big to fit in memory, or, in general you need the efficiency.

It combines

- a memory map¹
- string views²
- standard algorithms

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e399584e8622eb3)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/string_view.hpp>
#include <deque>

namespace io = boost::iostreams;

using boost::string_view;

auto map_entries(string_view input) {
    std::deque<string_view> pairs;

    while (!input.empty()) {
        size_t pos = input.find('\n');

        if (pos != string_view::npos)
            pos = input.find('\n', pos + 1);

        if (pos != string_view::npos)
            pairs.push_back(input.substr(0, pos));

        input.remove_prefix(pos + 1); // safe with unsigned wrap around
    }

    return pairs;
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    io::mapped_file_source file("input.txt");

    auto data = map_entries({ file.data(), file.size() });

    std::stable_sort(data.begin(), data.end());

    for (auto entry : data)
        std::cout << entry << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
& AAAAAAB 
is
& AAABBAB
this
& BABABAB
text
& BBBBBA
example
& BCAAAA
an
```

---

¹ it's trivial to use [POSIX mmap](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/mmap.html) instead of the boost thing there
² you can use [`std::[experimental::]string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) if your compiler/library is recent enough